# jquery filter is faulty and shows all results

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a couple of `divs` that I'm trying to filter them according to some dropdown filters. I'm using a `data-product_cost=true` attribute to list to filter them, so if I were to pick `product_cost` in the dropdown, all product divs with the `product_cost=true` attribute would show up the list and not any of the rest.

From the "Kontogebühren" dropdown list, if “Kostenlose Kontoführung” is selected, currently it shows all the cards. it should show only N26, Comdirect and DKB cards for the “Kostenlose Kontoführung” option selection.

// select tag

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery("#products-filter").change(function() {
    filtering_vergleiche();
  });

  filtering_vergleiche();

  function filtering_vergleiche() {

    var choosen_filter = [];
    jQuery('.product-item').removeClass('filter_hidden');
    jQuery('.filter_no_results').remove();

    jQuery('.products-filter select option:selected').each(function(index) {

      var current_filter_name = jQuery(this).attr('name');

      var current_filter_value = jQuery(this).attr('value');

      //Create object with all necessary info
      choosen_filter.push({
        "name": current_filter_name,
        "value": current_filter_value
      });
    });
    count_item = 0;
    count_hidden = 0;
    jQuery('.product-item').each(function(index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < choosen_filter.length; ++i) {
        choosen_filter_item = choosen_filter[i];
        choosen_filter_name = choosen_filter_item.name;
        choosen_filter_value = choosen_filter_item.value;

        filter_value_on_product = jQuery(this).attr('data-' + choosen_filter_name);

        if (choosen_filter_value != 'alle') {
          if (filter_value_on_product.indexOf(',') > -1) {
            let segments = filter_value_on_product.split(',').map(element => element.trim());;
            if (!segments.includes(choosen_filter_value)) {
              jQuery(this).addClass('filter_hidden');
            }
          } else if (filter_value_on_product != choosen_filter_value) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('filter_hidden');
          }
        }
      }
      count_item++;
    });

    jQuery('.product-item.filter_hidden').each(function(index) {
      count_hidden++;
    });

    //Nachricht anzeigen wenn keine Produkte gefunden wurden
    if (count_hidden == count_item) {
      jQuery("<p class='filter_no_results'>Zu dieser Auswahl wurden leider keine Ergebnisse gefunden.<br>Bitte andere Kriterien auswählen.<p>").appendTo('.product-item-listing');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <select id="filter_checkboxes" class="vergleich_select" size="1" name="term">
    <option id="filter_all" name="filter_alle" value="alle">
      Alle
    </option>
    <option id="product_cost" name="product_cost" value="true">
      Kostenlose Kontoführung
    </option>
    <option id="incentive" name="incentive" value="true">
      Mit Startguthaben
    </option>
  </select>
  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="false" data-atm_euro_fee="false" data-atm_international_fee="false" data- incoming_pm_min="true" data-product_cost="true">
    N26
  </div>
  <div class="product-item " data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data- incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    ComDirect
  </div>
  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data- incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    DKB
  </div>

  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="true" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="false" data-incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    Revolut
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find what's faulty in the `filtering_vergleiche()` function as I'm a bit of a newbie to jQuery.

Comment: FYI you can just do `count_hidden = jQuery('.product-item.filter_hidden').length`

Comment: What problem are you having? Is it showing items that should be hidden, or hiding items that should be shown?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it is showing items that should be hidden. as i'm a complete beginner to jquery, i find it challenging to reproduce it using leaner html body as the original one is quite big in size to paste here

Comment: We don't need all of it, just 3-4 items and the `<select>`

Comment: I added an update

Comment: Can you put it into a stack snippet so we can try to run it (see the link above for the instructions)? You also have an extra `<` before `<html>`

Comment: @Barmar added snippet

Comment: A bit of formatting shows your HTML is invalid

Comment: `jQuery("#products-filter")` should be `jQuery("#filter_checkboxes")`. So the function is never running.

Comment: This is also wrong: `jQuery('.products-filter select option:selected')` There's no `class="products-filter"`. And it's not a multi-select, so there's no need to loop over it. Just use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the dropdown.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, i did try to run `jQuery(#filter_checkboxes)` instead. it still lists all the products rather than only the first three.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all in your selectors.

The `.change()` handler should be on `jQuery("#filter_checkboxes").

The loop to get option values should use `jQuery("#filter_checkboxes option:selected")`.

You need CSS for `.filter_hidden` to hide the element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery("#filter_checkboxes").change(function() {
    filtering_vergleiche();
  });

  filtering_vergleiche();

  function filtering_vergleiche() {

    var choosen_filter = [];
    jQuery('.product-item').removeClass('filter_hidden');
    jQuery('.filter_no_results').remove();

    jQuery('#filter_checkboxes option:selected').each(function(index) {

      var current_filter_name = jQuery(this).attr('name');

      var current_filter_value = jQuery(this).attr('value');

      //Create object with all necessary info
      choosen_filter.push({
        "name": current_filter_name,
        "value": current_filter_value
      });
    });
    count_item = 0;
    count_hidden = 0;
    jQuery('.product-item').each(function(index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < choosen_filter.length; ++i) {
        choosen_filter_item = choosen_filter[i];
        choosen_filter_name = choosen_filter_item.name;
        choosen_filter_value = choosen_filter_item.value;

        filter_value_on_product = jQuery(this).attr('data-' + choosen_filter_name);

        if (choosen_filter_value != 'alle') {
          if (filter_value_on_product.indexOf(',') > -1) {
            let segments = filter_value_on_product.split(',').map(element => element.trim());;
            if (!segments.includes(choosen_filter_value)) {
              jQuery(this).addClass('filter_hidden');
            }
          } else if (filter_value_on_product != choosen_filter_value) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('filter_hidden');
          }
        }
      }
      count_item++;
    });

    jQuery('.product-item.filter_hidden').each(function(index) {
      count_hidden++;
    });

    //Nachricht anzeigen wenn keine Produkte gefunden wurden
    if (count_hidden == count_item) {
      jQuery("<p class='filter_no_results'>Zu dieser Auswahl wurden leider keine Ergebnisse gefunden.<br>Bitte andere Kriterien auswählen.<p>").appendTo('.product-item-listing');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.filter_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <select id="filter_checkboxes" class="vergleich_select" size="1" name="term">
    <option id="filter_all" name="filter_alle" value="alle">
      Alle
    </option>
    <option id="product_cost" name="product_cost" value="true">
      Kostenlose Kontoführung
    </option>
    <option id="incentive" name="incentive" value="true">
      Mit Startguthaben
    </option>
  </select>
  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="false" data-atm_euro_fee="false" data-atm_international_fee="false" data- incoming_pm_min="true" data-product_cost="true">
    N26
  </div>
  <div class="product-item " data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data- incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    ComDirect
  </div>
  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data- incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    DKB
  </div>

  <div class="product-item" data-incentive="true" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="false" data-incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">
    Revolut
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you are going with this.  A good number of syntax issues I fixed - post the HTML in an HTML validator to see those.

Here I added a few options to make it more illustrative when you select (I changed to `multiple` so you can pick more than one)

I used colors and a data attribute to do some to show what has been chosen.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#filter_select").on('change', filtering_vergleiche).first().trigger('change');
  //triggered instead of calling: filtering_vergleiche();

  function filtering_vergleiche(event) {
    let choosen_filter = [];
    $('.product-item').each(function() {
      this.dataset.chosen = "false";
    });
    let $choices = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('.product-item').removeClass('filter_hidden');
    $('.product-item-listing').find('.filter_no_results').remove();
    // nothing picked so get out of here
    if (!$choices.length) {
      return;
    }
    $choices.each(function(index) {
      choosen_filter.push({
        "name": $(this).attr('name'),
        "value": $(this).attr('value')
      });
    });
    let $products = $('.product-item');
    let count_item = $products.length; //0;
    let count_hidden = 0;
    $products.each(function(index) {
      let isChoice = this.dataset.chosen == "true";
      // we already chose it so go to next one
      if (isChoice) return;
      for (var i = 0; i < choosen_filter.length; ++i) {
        let choosen_filter_item = choosen_filter[i];
        let choosen_filter_name = choosen_filter_item.name;
        let choosen_filter_value = choosen_filter_item.value;

        let filter_value_on_product = $(this).data(choosen_filter_name);
        filter_value_on_product = filter_value_on_product || $(this).data('choice') == choosen_filter_value;
        this.dataset.chosen = this.dataset.chosen == "true" || choosen_filter_value == 'alle' || filter_value_on_product ? "true" : "false";
      }
    });
    let hiddenOnes = $('.product-item').filter('.filter_hidden');
    count_hidden = hiddenOnes.length;
    if (count_hidden == count_item) {
      $("<p class='filter_no_results'>Zu dieser Auswahl wurden leider keine Ergebnisse gefunden.<br>Bitte andere Kriterien auswählen.<p>").appendTo('.product-item-listing');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.filter_hidden {
  border: solid green 1px;
}

.vergleich_select {
  height: 6rem;
}

.product-item-listing {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.product-item[data-chosen="true"] {
  background-color: #ddffdd44;
}

.product-item[data-chosen="false"] {
  background-color: #ddddff44;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="filter_select" class="vergleich_select" size="1" name="term" multiple>
  <option name="filter_alle" value="alle" data-choice="all">
    Alle (All)
  </option>
  <option name="product_cost" value="true" data-choice="product_cost">
    Kostenlose Kontoführung (Free Account Management)
  </option>
  <option name="incentive" value="true" data-choice="incentive">
    Mit Startguthaben (With starting credit)
  </option>
  <option name="incoming_pm_min" value="true" data-choice="incoming_pm_min">
    incoming_pm_min = true
  </option>
  <option name="incentive" value="true" data-choice="partnercard">
    partnercard = true
  </option>
  <option name="incentive" value="true" data-choice="atm_international_fee">
    atm_international_fee = true
  </option>
</select>

<div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="false" data-atm_euro_fee="false" data-atm_international_fee="false" data-incoming_pm_min="true" data-product_cost="true">N26</div>
<div class="product-item " data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data-incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">ComDirect</div>
<div class="product-item" data-incentive="false" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="true" data- incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">DKB</div>
<div class="product-item" data-incentive="true" data-partnercard="true" data-atm_euro_fee="true" data-atm_international_fee="false" data-incoming_pm_min="false" data-product_cost="true">Revolut</div>
<div class="product-item-listing">empty</div>
```